# Java swing- Can I change the name on the tab when an event is fired?

Tags: java, string, swing, tabs, action

First, the code:

```
tab_textArea_file.addTab(docLabel, null, scrollPane_textArea, null);
```

So the situation is that I have a list of files the user can select from. When a user clicks on a file, the contents of the file is read and loaded into a textArea. "docLabel" (which is in the code above) is the string that's suppose to change to the name of the file selected, but it doesn't. Is it possible for to change the name within docLabel from the code above? I've tested it with a JOptionPane (works), but it's  not working within a tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
int index = tab_textArea_file.getSelectedIndex();
tab_textArea_file.setTitleAt(index, "New Title");
```

Answer (score 3):

from java doc i see

```
setTitleAt(int index, String title)
```

you could take index of tab clicked and change is name

Answer (score 1):

You can know the selected tab index by calling

```
int selectedIndex = tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
```

and then after your file is selected call

```
tabbedPane.setTitleAt(selectedIndex, "New Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had issue with the `setTitleAt(int index, String title)` : If the title doesn't appears, try to replace:

```
tab_textArea_file.setTitleAt(index, docLabel);
```

with:

```
tab_textArea_file.setTitleAt(index, new String(docLabel));
```